# Find duplicate Numbers repeated more than once C#

Tags: c#, arrays

How do we find duplicates number in int array repeated more than two times. One of the example I have is as below

```
public static void main()
{
      int[] array = { 3, 7, 9 , 7, 4, 9, 7 , 9}
      Dictionary<int,int> dic = new Dictionary<int,int>();
      foreach(var Val in array)
      {
         if(dict.containskey(Val)
           dic[Val] ++;
         else 
           dic[Val] = 1 ;
      }

   foreach (var pair in dic)
      if(key.value > 2 )
         Console.WriteLine(pair.key)
}
```

Is there any better way to do this? I was been asked in one of the interview. I gave above solution which was been rejected.

Edit :: I was been asked to write a program which takes less memory and good in performance.. It should not use linq or any inbuilt C# extension method...

Comment: Define "better". The code snippet will not compile with C# compiler by the  way.

Comment: your code snippet won't compile, you use capital case everywhere

Comment: I am sorry I posted this from mobile, I will edit it..

Comment: [Element distinctness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there aren't any constraints provided to the elements that can be contained in this array, you should have asked the interviewer whether he wants a solution with O(n) time complexity and O(n) space complexity** or a solution with O(nlogn) time complexity and O(1) space complexity**.

Without constraints to the elements in the array there's no solution in O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity**.

And because he rejected your solution (which is O(n) time complexity and O(n) space complexity**) apparently he was seeking for the second. One way to achieve that is to first sort the array and then iterate over it to find the duplicates.

Remark**: the example values provided for space complexity do not include the space occupied by the original array, only the extra space needed.

Comment: Sorting array and finding duplicates wouldn't be costly?

Comment: Yes, sorting is `O(nlogn)` complexity in average. The benefit is that you achieve that in O(1) space complexity. If you want a faster algorithm then you could use the approach you suggested but it will take more memory because you are using another dictionary. That's why you should have asked the interviewer whether he is seeking an algorithm that is fast or one that doesn't take much memory. Both are not possible unfortunately, or at least not with classic algorithms :-)

Comment: Unfortunately interviewer was not yet introduced, only paper with one question was given to us.. if I remember it correctly, they were looking for good memory management..

Comment: In this case your solution is wrong because while it has better time complexity it uses more memory because of the additional hashtable that you use. So I guess he was looking for another solution that would not involve copying the items into another data structure.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't exactly call it a bottleneck. Your solution is also good and valid, it just all depends on the requirements and the context. That's why it is very important to always understand the problem very well and define all the possible constraints that we need to deal with in advance before trying to solve it.

Answer (score 7):

Group your items and take only those with more than 2 occurrences:

```
array.GroupBy(x=>x).Where(x=>x.Count()>2).Select(x=>x.Key)
```

Comment: it was  not in your starting question.

Comment: My mistake.. apologies.

Comment: It's a good answer if OP is asked in SQL language. Interview question like this one is never intended to show how you are familiar with libraries or language features.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void FindRepeating(int[] input) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        var abs = Math.Abs(input[i]);

        if (input[abs] >= 0)
            input[abs] = -input[abs];
        else
            Console.Write(abs + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Int[] array = { 3, 7, 9 , 7, 4, 9, 7 , 9};
string duplicates="";
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
 {
   for (int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++)
    {
       if(array[i]==array[j])
        {
          duplicates+=Convert.tostring(array[i]) + ",";
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: That's O(n*n) which is even slower than OP's solution.

Comment: Repeated sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution is to sort array of numbers, then to count equal sequent numbers in sorted array. Complexity of such approach is O (N log N) where N is count of numbers in array. For this purpose you can use `List<int>` type. It contains needed sort method.

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest to do the following:**

- Find the `Max` value in **array** .
- Create a `Frequent Array` with size: `Maxvalue + 1`.
- loop throw array and update `Frequent Array` based on **array** value.

  ```
          int[] array = { 3, 7, 9, 7, 4, 9, 7, 9 };
          int length = array.Length;
          int Maxvalue = array.Max();
          int[] FrequentArray = new int[Maxvalue + 1];
          for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
          {
              FrequentArray[array[i]]++;
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < Maxvalue + 1; i++)
          {
              if (FrequentArray[i] > 2)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(i);
              }
          }
  ```

The complexity would be >>> **O(N logN + Maxvalue)**

Comment: @n0rd ,, will you test the complexity of my algorithm ?

Comment: why are you taking `MaxValue + 1` of input array as a length of `FrequentArray` ? You could have use simply `Dictionary<int,int>`. What if maximum value of input array is 10,000 but total elements in input array is just 5 ?

Comment: @AmitMaheshwari The point of **NOT** using Dictionary is to avoid the complexity of using  `.containskey(Val)`

Comment: @AmitMaheshwari in many situation my algorithm would be the best approach, But not every single situation.In case maximum value of input array is relatively higher than the size of the **arrray**, he should use `Dictionary` .

Comment: putting an edit, which I think is not much complex. Have a look

Comment: @AmitMaheshwari the Edit you suggest is not differ than the OP's solution.

Comment: yes it is, and Linq is the best for this problem, but if input is from user, it is safe approach. It seems better in terms of `Space` required and also excepting additional `if` condition check it is same as original algorithm you wrote(ultimately if condition check will be there too, but internally) - in terms of `Processing`

Comment: @ManthanDavda the only built in method used here is array.Max(); , you can do it manually with O(log N) complexity. and it won't affect the general complexity of my algorithm.